# System.Net.Sockets.Socket

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi
I have a chat program using System.Net.Sockets.Socket that works perfectly over LAN.

My question is - will this same program work over the net with little or no modification and if so do i provide the client with the IP of my machine or of my router and use port forwarding ?

My IP is NOT static (i do understand the implications of this)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should work identically, as long as you can get a connection through. there is technically no difference between lan communication and internet communication (one is just huge and complex)